# Is it true that $\int_{a}^b h^2=0\implies h=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am working on a few examples where my author said this is true if $h$ is continuous. Can someone explain why? Just because the integral is $0$ doesn't mean the integrand is zero as well.

$\int_{a}^b h^2=0\implies h=0$?

Comment: Take $h(a) = 1$ and $h(x)= 0$ otherwise.

Comment: Try drawing a picture of $h$, $h^2$ and what it would mean that $\int h^2=0$.

Comment: For real $h$, the square $h^2$ is non-negative, so it the curve $h^2$ is never below the $x$-axis. This means the integral is the total area under the curve $h^2$ (without any cancellations due to part of the curve being below the $x$-axis), and if this is zero, then the value at each point is also zero (and there are no points of discontinuity with isolated non-zero values, as the function is continuous).

Comment: It is true if $h$ is continuous, or, for Lebesgue measure, if $h=0$ a.e ("almost everywhere.")

Comment: @John That is discontinuous.

Comment: @M.Vinay: The $h$ I suggested is meant to be a counterexample.

Comment: @John: A counterexample to what? The claim is that $\int_a^bh^2=0\implies h=0,$ if $h$ is continuous.

Comment: @CameronBuie: You are right. I misread "if" to "only if" in the question.

Answer (score 9):

If $h$ is a continuous, real-valued function and takes on a non-zero value in the interval $[a,b],$ then there is some interval $(c,d)\subset[a,b]$ in which $h$ is non-zero, so $h^2$ is positive. In particular, by choosing the interval $(c,d)$ with a little care, we can show that there is some $K>0$ such that $h^2>K$ on $(c,d),$ so that $$0<(d-c)K\le\int_c^dh^2\le\int_a^bh^2.$$ That last inequality is due to the fact that $h^2$ is a nonnegative function.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $h$ is real, suppose that $h(x_0) \neq 0$ for some $x_0 \in (a,b)$. Then $h^2(x) > 0$. But if $h^2$ integrates to zero, and $h^2(x)$ is positive somewhere and continuous, then we must have $h^2(x) < 0$ for some $x$. Can you see the problem with it now?